# Can you find me

Tags: logical-deduction, mathematics, word-problem

if you divide my first digit by my last digit then you can find me for ever

If you multiply me by any number equal to or less than my length (but greater than zero) and I will only cycle.

If you divide any number equal to or less than my length (but greater than zero) by the last digit of me you will still find me for ever in different cycles

Comment: When you say in the second line "and multiply the rest of me" does this mean excluding the last digit?

Comment: Edited that part out....

Comment: should the first line read, if you divide me by my last digit, you can find me for ever?

Comment: I think that part is right

Comment: -1/-1 would be +1 right you wont find me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are

> $142857$

Because

> $\frac17 = 0.\overline{142857}$

And

> $142857\times2=285714$
>  $142857\times3=428571$
>  $142857\times4=571428$
>  $142857\times5=714285$
>  $142857\times6=857142$

And finally:

> $\frac27 = 0.\overline{285714}$, but it can be rewritten as $0.2857\overline{142857}$
>  $\frac37 = 0.\overline{428571}=0.42857\overline{142857}$
>  $\frac47 = 0.\overline{571428}=0.57\overline{142857}$
>  $\frac57 = 0.\overline{714285}=0.7\overline{142857}$
>  $\frac67 = 0.\overline{857142}=0.857\overline{142857}$

The way to find it is actually not that difficult:

> After you recognise that "cycle" refers to the repeating digits you need to ask what single-digit denominators produce repeating patterns in decimal. We have 3, 6, 7, 9 as candidates. However: 3, 6, and 9 produce repeating pattern of a single digit for any single-digit numerator, so we know that the last digit must be 7. So we try 1 as the first digit and it works.

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: @skv Oh, i see )))

Comment: @skv, is this the answer?

Comment: If it is, i'll add the explanation of how i found it.

Comment: I will wait for edit

Comment: I think your answer needs to reflect my question edit :)

Comment: @skv Your edited version makes no sense "If you divide any number equal to or less than my length (but greater than zero) you will still find me for ever". What does that mean? If you divide it by what?

Comment: Sorry... I just couldn't word it well... :) see now

Comment: Ok, unless you'll change the question again, my answer now reflects the current version and has the explanation.